# Chinese Chars not displayed properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have utf8 encoded data in Database.

The data is displayed properly in **PHPMYADMIN** on both local and remote databases.

I am using **codeigniter** and **twitter bootstrap** to display this Data.

The data gets displayed properly on my Local Windows computer But the same

is replaced with ç�¼ç��è��è�±  chars on remote website.

What am i doing wrong ?

Update:

The chars are displayed properly on removing **htmlentities()** function from the data but what if the data contains html tags that mess up the webpage

Comment: I suggest you start by checking out the source and the headers of the phpmyadmin page against your remote website. Encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this in the html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If not add it.

Comment: or `<meta charset="utf-8" />` if you want to be all futuristic ;)

Comment: I am using CI and twitter bootstrap which are default UTF8 and HTML 5.  I have <html lang="en">

<meta charset="utf-8"> in source

Comment: You also might need to have the character sets installed in your actual client computer.

Comment: The chars are displayed properly on removing htmlentities() function from the data but what if the data contains html tags that mess up the webpage

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php sais about the $encoding param that is defaults to "ISO-8859-1" for PHP versions olders then 5.4.

Comment: I believe chinese encoding is UTF-16

Comment: It should work with UTF-8 (I used it before ;). @Solution, did that fixed the problem?

Comment: Yes . But to avoid problems now im using htmlspecialchars() .Thanks :)

Comment: Also i dont know how to read chinese . But they now look like chinese :P

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your remote server sends the correct headers.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Make sure that your files in **utf-8** encoding.